# Equation with exponential functions 4

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, radicals

> Solve the following equation(without utilising calculus):
>   $$ 2005^x-2004^x=1+ 3 \cdot (2004^{\frac{x}{3}} +2004^{\frac{2x}{3}}) $$

I've tried switching everything to the other side of the inequality except      $ 2005^x$ to then divide by it and have observed the function resulted from it is always positive but I haven't been able to progress further; I should find the intersection of said function $ f(x)=\frac{1}{2005^x} + (\frac{2004^{1/3}}{2005})^x +(\frac{2004^{
2/3}}{2005})^x+ (\frac{2004}{2005})^x  $   with  $1$ to solve the equation.(There probably are better methods than this which I'm unaware of).

Comment: $$x=3$$ is one solution. Where can i find the other equations?

Comment: other equations meaning?

Comment: equations with exponential functions 1,2,3?

Comment: already answered, you can see them on my profile

Comment: Ok thank you, i have found it

Comment: Hint: Find the value of $(a+1)^3-a^3$.